# According to Protestant belief, when did Jesus present His blood into the Holy of Holies as required by Law?

Tags: life-of-jesus, crucifixion, redemption

In the Old testament, it was important for the High priest to present a bowl of pure, spotless blood in the Holies of Holies.  If accepted by Jehovah, the Israelites would be in God's favor.

In the New Testament, it is revealed that Jesus, as High Priest, presented a bowl,*but this time, His own blood* and placed it in the Holy of Holies (spiritually speaking: in the heavenlies). Hebrews 9:7,11-14.

*But only the High Priest entered the inner room, and that only once a year, and never without blood which he offered for himself and for the sins of the people...(Jesus) did not enter by mens of the blood of goats and calves, but He entered the Most Holy Place once for all by His own blood, having obtained eternal redemption.* (NIV, 1984)

*In Him (Jesus) we have redemption through His blood, the forgiveness of sins.* (Ephesians 1:7, NIV)

When during the Passion week did this happen?

Comment: Which translation of the Bible is quoted here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Atoning Blood Presentation** All the comments and answers given are greatly appreciated.  Here are a few observations that one might consider along these lines to aid in a resolution of the question.

1. Any ascending to the heavenly tabernacle on Friday would be spiritual.  And this would not be unusual since there is more to reality in the spirit realm, than in our physical universe. (This not to say individuals are not recognizable without a physical body: Moses and Elijah were recognizable on the mount of Transfiguration, etc. The thief would recognize Jesus on the way up to Paradise.)  The *physical* Ascension would be a later manifestation.
2. That the first Ascension was on Friday is determined by Jesus own words. The "comma" is placed in the correct position in the NIV translation. It comes naturally *after* the personal phrase Jesus used throughout His ministry: *Verily I say unto you.* He never said, "I say unto you today". So all this happened on Friday afternoon (evening?).
3. That the **Paradise** in question is not Sheol nor Hades (the underworld) can be discerned by its usage in the N.T. (We do not have to appeal to Persian, Armenian, Old Testament, or rabbinical tradition.)  (a) 2 Cor. 12:4-Paul associates it with the heavenlies. (b) Rev. 2:7-John related it to the Tree of Life (in heaven). These refer to an upward movement, not down to Sheol.  In fact Jesus never used the word, Sheol, to the thief.
4. The idea that Jesus did not already go to heaven is dispelled by the understanding that most modern translations of John 20:17 do not use the word, "touch," but rather "don't cling" or "don't hold on to Me." This removes the idea of contamination by Mary which would prevent Jesus from entering the Holy of Holies. It merely means Jesus had a lot more things to accomplish before the final physical Ascension. (Acts 1)
5. If the *blood of redemption* was not presented until 40 days later after the Crucifixion, it would have been sorely congealed. It would have been more appropriate to apply it right after the Lamb of God was slain! (Friday) Just like it was in the old sacrificial system.
6. Jesus would have had plenty of time to do all the other spiritual events Jesus is recorded to have done in the underworld, between Friday and Sunday morning. (Which is another irrelevant topic here.)

What do all these considerations point to? What conclusions can we draw from  them? Do they pinpoint the time of Jesus atonement...or not?

It seems, however, that the use of "today" by Jesus limits it to *Friday*. And the Ascension Jesus referred to when talking to Mary was the "physical ascension" which happened 40 days later.  The next sentence about telling the disciple He "was ascending" (present tense) expands on this idea: it was a lengthy process in order to wrap things up on earth.

Note that symbols, analogies, types, etc. all have their limitations. So the blood that Jesus carried would have been "spiritual" not physical, just as the new tabernacle was also not physical...and the right hand of God is not physical! But the spiritual realities are much greater than the physical ones; so Jesus's blood is indeed redemptive to the max (Eph. 1:7)!

Comment: This looks more like an elaboration of the question than an answer

Comment: @anne  see the points made in the Op “answer” here

Comment: @User 14 See additional edit.  One has often the need to lay a "ground-work" before answering a question to give it a substantial footing. To reiterate: the N.T. use of Paradise in an upward movement (not a downward Sheol)...and the word of Jesus, "Today"...and the customary (Law of Moses) presentation of the blood right after the slaying of the Lamb...all point to the time as Friday afternoon.

Answer (score 6):

My reading of the chapter in Hebrews is that his version of "entering the Holy Place" was entering the presence of God. "For Christ has entered not into a sanctuary made with hands, a copy of the true one, but into heaven itself, now to appear in the presence of God on our behalf" (v24, RSV) He gained access to this real sanctuary by his own blood (v12), whereas the ordinary priest can enter only the "copy" sanctuary, the physical sanctuary, "with blood not his own" (v25).

If we are obliged to define a timing for these events, we might identify the moment of "entering the sanctuary" with the Ascension, when he reaches the presence of his Father in a more direct sense. In which case, that would also be the moment when he "presented the blood".

Though it might be better to regard it as a timeless event, associated with the fact of Crucifixion-and-Resurrection.

I don't think this is a peculiarly Protestant interpretation. Just a scriptural one.

Comment: .Thank God the results of the Presentation of  the redemptive blood is "timeless" deserving of a continual gratitude and worship!  And I am not sure but Catholic and Orthodox churches would all rejoice in this.  Have you considered that, while Jesus ascended "physically" after 40 days  (43?), that possibly He ascended on Friday (with the thief in tow) "spiritually" into the spiritual sanctuary with the bowl of blood?  It would not have  congealed at that time  as it would have 40 days later.  What do you think?

Comment: @anne comment by OP here

Answer (score 1):

**At no point did Jesus Christ present his own blood in the most holy part of the earthly temple in Jerusalem.**  The book of Hebrews shows him ascending in glory to the Father in heaven, and there presenting his blood. The whole of chapter 9 goes into this. The first 7 verses speak of earthly animal sacrifices, with the High Priest entering but once a year into the Most Holy, with a bowl containing blood, which he offered for his own sins, and those of the Israelites. Now comes the link to Jesus Christ:

> "The Holy Ghost thus signifying that the way into the holiest of all
> was not yet made manifest, while as the first tabernacle was yet
> standing: which was a figure for the time then present, ...until the
> time of reformation. But Christ being come an high priest of good
> things to come, by a greater and more perfect tabernacle, not made
> with hands, that is to say, not of this building; neither by the blood
> of goats and calves, but by his own blood he entered in once into the
> holy place, having obtained eternal redemption." Hebrews 9:8-12 A.V.

There is no mention of a bowl (or scarlet wool or hyssop) when the risen Christ offered his blood in the throne-room of heaven. The reason why not is contained in the following verses:

> "It was therefore necessary that the patterns of things in the heavens
> should be purified by these [sprinkled blood of animals] but the
> heavenly things themselves with better sacrifices than these. ***For
> Christ is not entered into the holy places made with hands***, which are
> the figures of the true; but into heaven itself, now to appear in the
> presence of God for us." (*Ibid*, vss. 23-24) [Square brackets and bold italics mine.]

Christ did not enter into the Most Holy part of the temple in Jerusalem at any time during his earthly life, or after his death. As for, ***"as required by Law" (in the question)*** that Law only pertained to the earthly things prior to the once-for-all-time perfect sacrifice of Christ. At the point of his death on the cross, the immensely thick, woven tapestry in the temple on earth was supernaturally rent asunder, from top to bottom, signifying the spiritual way now being opened into the very presence of God - Christ being the one to first enter in to the heavenly reality.

Bear in mind what happened to the Law at the point of Christ nailed to the cross:

> "Blotting out the handwriting of ordinances that was against us, which
> was contrary to us, and **took it out of the way, nailing it to the
> cross**." Colossians 2:14 A.V. [Bold mine]

This means that the requirements on earth for temple sacrifices had permanently ended, for God's people. Therefore, the risen Christ could go to heaven to present the value of his shed blood. We are told a few verses further on (in Col. 3:1) that Christ was sitting on the right hand of God. **So, the answer to the question is** that ***at some point after Christ died on earth, he ascended to stand before God, presented the blood of the new covenant, then sat down at God's right hand.*** That can be narrowed down to Jesus telling Mary on the morning of his resurrection not to cling on to him, for ***he had not yet ascended to the Father*** (John 20:17). Some Protestants may have pinned it down to a more exact time, but it is the fact that it happened, unseen by us, in heaven, that should be all of our consideration and joy.

Comment: Clarify whether or not Jesus presented any actual physical blood in heaven. Also did Jesus ascend to heaven more than once?  Some seem to be saying  his ascension 40 days after resurrection was not when the value of his sacrifice was presented.  Instead Jesus popped into the heavenly holy place right after he spoke to Mary  according to SLM’s answer

Comment: @User 14   If the OP wishes me to clarify the points you raise, I will consider doing that. As it is, you have listed various points that require separate questions on this site. Comments are not for starting debates or for setting one answerer up against another. Each answer stands (or falls) on its own merits (or demerits) and it is up to the OP to make decisions about that. Your points are interesting and good, but this is not the way to get responses to them, I would respectfully suggest.

Comment: Op does ask specifically about the bowl of blood being presented in the heavenly holies.   Somewhere in comments Op was intimating that Jesus would have needed to get to heaven quickly before the blood congealed.

Comment: @User 14  I specifically answered that no bowl, red cord, or hyssop is mentioned in the Hebrews account of Christ entering heaven. As for the OP hinting at a need to get to heaven quickly before the blood congealed; I re-read the Q and found no hint of such an idea. The matter of blood congealing would only ever apply to things happening on earth, in the physical realm. Christ's offering was in heaven.

Comment: Find Op “answer” to his own question

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn’t this have been necessary for man. Jesus was not just man but God. The veil tearing in two shows me that this was not something Jesus needed to physically do within the temple as his own blood was spilled for our sins, the location of the blood doesn’t seem relevant since he is literally part of the Holy Trinity. He is literally the Holy of Holies

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Entering the Holy of Holies in the Old Testament occurred once per year on the day of atonement.  See also Lev 16:29-34.

> Also on the tenth day of this seventh month there shall be a day of atonement: it shall be an holy convocation unto you; and ye shall afflict your souls, and offer an offering made by fire unto the LORD. Lev 23:27

That would be the general pattern of the reality in Christ Jesus.  I say "general" because while the Old required annual sacrifices, Christ did this once for all time never to be repeated.  He does not suffer often.

> For then must he often have suffered since the foundation of the world: but now once in the end of the world hath he appeared to put away sin by the sacrifice of himself. Heb 9:26

But when did entering the heavenly Holy of Holies take place?  Was it during His time in the tomb, ascension 40 days later, or some 6 months later at Atonement day or centuries later?  Or does the bible tell us?

Recall the event between Mary Magdalene and Christ in the garden after He rose out from the dead.

> Jesus saith unto her, Touch me not; for I am not yet ascended to my Father: but go to my brethren, and say unto them, I ascend unto my Father, and your Father; and to my God, and your God. John 20:17

Touch me not because He had yet to ascend to His Father.  This is an oblique reference to the High Priest at Atonement.

> And there shall be no man in the tabernacle of the congregation when he [Levitical High Priest] goeth in to make an atonement in the holy place, until he come out, and have made an atonement for himself, and for his household, and for all the congregation of Israel. Lev 16:17

In other words, Mary should not have been present, let alone touching Him.  However, once He completed atonement, it was perfectly fine to touch.

> Then saith he to Thomas, Reach hither thy finger, and behold my hands; and reach hither thy hand, and thrust it into my side: and be not faithless, but believing. John 20:27

There is one other piece, the requirement that the one making a Testament must die before it is in effect.

> For where a testament is, there must also of necessity be the death of the testator. Heb 9:16

Christ made the Testament at the Last Supper and death.  And then resurrected for our life.

> So Christ was once offered to bear the sins of many; and unto them that look for him shall he appear the second time without sin unto salvation. Heb 9:28

So, to answer the OP from this Protestant point of view, when did Christ enter the heavenly Holy of Holies?

Within minutes of His resurrection, He ascended into the heavenly Holy of Holies.

TO ADD: Christ is explicit about the timing of ascending to God in John 20:17.  He tells Mary, I ascend.

> Jesus saith unto her, Touch me not; for I am not yet ascended to my Father: but go to my brethren, and say unto them, I **ascend** unto my Father, and your Father; and to my God, and your God.

"Ascend" is in the present tense.  She leaves, He ascends.

Yes, that same day He also descends back to earth.

> Then the same day at evening, being the first day of the week, when the doors were shut where the disciples were assembled for fear of the Jews, came Jesus and stood in the midst, and saith unto them, Peace be unto you. John 20:19

Later the same day, He shows them His wounds to prove Himself who He is.

Comment: “Within minutes of His resurrection, He ascended into the heavenly Holy of Holies.”   Was this as a spirit or as a physical man?

Comment: Now this I say, brethren, that flesh and blood cannot inherit the kingdom of God; neither doth corruption inherit incorruption. 1 Cor 15:50  Yet, He told Thomas to touch His wounds.  So, spirit and flesh.  Able to eat and walk through doors.

Comment: What support can you offer for your claim that “within minutes of His resurrection Jesus was in the heavenly holy of holies?” Especially in light of John 20:17?

Comment: I mention John 20:17 as an oblique reference to Lev 16:17.  Based on that connection, I do assume that Jesus and Mary's conversation lasted only minutes.  He says, don't touch me.  I am not yet ascended to My Father (ascended is in perfect tense, meaning a once for all time completed never to be repeated.  They depart.  Mary to tell.  Christ to the heavenly Holy of Holies.

Comment: Nope. Jesus Ascends once for all time. There were many encounters for a good while after the conversation with Mary before Jesus ascends to his father Luke 24:50-53

Comment: @SLMAren't we ignoring the ascent to Paradise that Jesus made with the born-again thief "right after the crucifixion"?  This way the recently made blood sacrifice could supply the needed bowl of blood for offering in the heavenly sanctuary.  After all, Jesus did declare that He would be ascending that day: Friday.

Comment: @raygrant depends on where you put the comma

Comment: @raygrant Some see "today you will be with me in paradise" as  referring to Abraham's bosom where Jesus preached unto those in captivity ... 1 Peter 3:19.

Comment: @User14  The pattern (Mosaic) was multiple visits up and down the mountain.  Moreover, Christ is returning (Acts 1:11).  Between resurrection and ascension Christ encountered many (1 Cor 15:5-8).  The question is about the timing of entering the heavenly Holy of Holies (Heb 9:24).  Based on the pattern and Christ's initial comment to Mary right after resurrection and subsequent encounters later that same day, I believe that was the time of His entering the heavenly Holy of Holies.

Comment: @raygrant I'd agree with Mike Borden about that, but its another good question.  Where was Jesus between death and resurrection.  Wasn't He only preaching during that time in "hades/sheol"?  Upon resurrection, then came others (first fruit see Mat 27:52).

Comment: @slm. You believe what you want . Answers here used to need support but oh well.   I believe the Bible which says Jesus ascended once for all time

Comment: @raygrant are you suggesting that Jesus presented the sin atoning blood of his sacrificial death in the heavenly most holy before he was resurrected?

Comment: @User14 you believe "ascended once for all time" which is to say you do not believe He will return in contrast to Acts 1:11, 1 Th 4:16, Rev 1:7.

Comment: Exactly  Jesus returns as a mighty spirit not as a physical man

Comment: It seems you are suggesting that God/Jesus was surprised that Mary was present near the tomb and had to react quickly to keep the whole ransom sacrifice from being annulled by an accidental encounter with her.

Comment: @User14 not exactly.  "Touch" is touch, cling, adhere to.  He says don't.  Later that same day its okay to interact.  Don't get confused by physical things interpreting spiritual things.

Comment: It is conjecture on your part to say that Jesus secretary went to heaven and initiated the new covenant with the value of his shed blood  shortly after telling Mary to stop clinging to him.   The scriptures tell us of one occasion when resurrected Jesus ascended to heaven. 10 days after that the events of Pentecost demonstrated that the new covenant was in effect.

Comment: except He says, I ascend in that John passage

Comment: “ I am ascending”. that remains true even though it would be 40 days later

Comment: (Friday) Most of the comments on this Answer ignore Jesus's other declaration:  "TODAY --Friday--you will be with me in Paradise." (The comma is in the right place)  The command to Mary was not "touch" but "don't cling to Me." So it had nothing to do with contamination. There is nothing in the scriptures that prohibit Jesus from going to God several times.  The final physical (resurrected body) Ascension does not detract from Jesus's activity beforehand.  In fact, He also had to be coronated  in heaven "before" His ascension, (Matt. 28:18). He was already given Authority ere the Great Comm...

Answer (score 0):

blood was taken into holy of holies only at day of atonement(Leviticus 16) not passover not day of Pentecost ,not on feasts of trumpets

accordingly during passover weekend,Jesus resurrected as the "first fruits from the dead",priest  used to harvest barley first fruits and wave it in front of the first curtain in Holy PLACE

Jesus did not get waved as the first fruits from the dead in the earthly sanctuary but he fulfilled it by ascending to heaven just before 9am on Sunday morning and presented Himself to the Father ...hear hear hear ...Jesus said to her, Do not cling to Me [do not hold Me], for I have not yet ascended to the Father. But go to My brethren and tell them, I am ascending to My Father and your Father, and to My God and your God.....that same evening he had come back from heaven and joined the disciples and breathed a  token of the Holy Spirit to them.His sacrifice had been accepted by the Father and we witness Fire(Holy Spirit ) as evidence of  acceptance .Fire came down to touch the sacrifice we remember ?after 40 days Christ ascended to the Father second time from Mt olives see acts 1.revelation 4:5 shows the Father and in front of the FATHER was the HOLY SPIRIT in symbols as seven burning lamps ...in revelation 5:6 the Holy Spirit IS NO LONGER in front of the throne but as seven EYES ON JESUS and then SENT TO EARTH.revelation 4 and 5 shows the arrival and inauguration of Jesus as Lord(seven horns) and Messiah(seven eyes) at ascension with  the sending of the HOLY SPIRIT .the ceremony in revelation 4 is taking place in a venue where IN FRONT OF THE THRONE SEVEN LAMPS WERE BLAZING (read revelation 4:5)....where do we find seven lamps ?.....that verse in verse 5 chapter  4 puts the throne in the HOLY PLACE on table of showbread( read again revelation 4:5 in front of the throne seven lamps were blazing ...lamps were placed on candlesticks in HOLY PLACE..we read .exodus 40:24 He put the lampstand in the tabernacle of meeting, across from the table, on the south side of the tabernacle; 25 and he lit the lamps before the Lord, as the Lord had commanded Moses.....in symbols Christ was crowned Lord and Messiah at the tableofshowbread throne and given the promise of seven lamps(holy SPIRIT) and then he sent the Holy Spirit to earth (read the last part of revelation 5:6)

in symbols the church is the candlestick (revelation 1:20) and the HOLY SPIRIT IS THE LAMPS  which sit on the church.thus pentecost is when lamps are placed on candletstick and then light up the candlestick !!!! thats a holy place activity !all this activity the priest is in the Holy place

when acts 2  happens Christ is confirming that His inauguration as priest and king was compete on heaven .Peter says it in his sermon ..‘The Lord said to my Lord,
“Sit at My right hand,( see revelation 5,the sitting at the right hand event)
35 Till I make Your enemies Your footstool.” we are still in the "till"...he eventually removes human kingdoms which are still present)
36 “Therefore let all the house of Israel know assuredly that God has made this Jesus, whom you crucified, both Lord and Christ.”..Peter does not use symbols in verse 36 as does John ...John uses two symbols to say the same things...in revelation 5:6....seven horns(Lord with full power) and seven eyes ( Anointed Messiah )

Christ is revealed in the book of revelation as a high priest who we see in holy place in revelation 1:12 revelation 4:5 and revelation 5:6 and revelation 8:3-5.we then begin to see the opening into the MOST HOLY PLACE in revelation 11:19 Then God’s temple(naos=inner shrine) in heaven was opened, and within his temple(inner shrine) was seen the ark of his covenant. And there came flashes of lightning, rumblings, peals of thunder, an earthquake and a severe hailstorm.

that verse tells us the Father is no longer in front of Seven lamps but in the MOST hOLY PLACE"was seen the ark of his covenant"..the ark of covenant was only seen during day of atonement .that part of the sanctuary was only opened during day of atonement ,not passover ,not day  of pentecost .the book of revelation does not give us a date when JesuS entered the MOST HOLY PLACE but we do see his activity in the HOLY PLACE from chapter 1 to chapter 11..probation will close in revelation 15:5-8!and thats when the day of atonement closes .There is no record as to when the Lord entered the Most hOLY PLACE but we know he entered the HOLY PLACE first .passover and day of penetcost do not have MOST HOLY PLACE as their venue at all.the  sanctuary and their rituals were given as a compacted prophecy of the gospel and their order "or pattern"must be respected.we will have to find other sources to find out when the "goat ceremony "( day of atonement )was fulfilled .we may need to find out other metaphors represented by day of atonement .For the Jews it was the day of judgment .It was a day of cleansing  of the sanctuary to remove all year round sins (leviticus 16).Christ s last ministry will be to close books  too. Daniel 7:9 “As I looked,

“thrones were set in place,
and the Ancient of Days took his seat.
His clothing was as white as snow;
the hair of his head was white like wool.
His throne was flaming with fire,
and its wheels were all ablaze.
10 A river of fire was flowing,
coming out from before him.
Thousands upon thousands attended him;
ten thousand times ten thousand stood before him.
The court was seated,
and the books were opened.

the end will be when saints are awarded the kingdom by a court process .thats the day of atonement metaphor in the sanctuary.Christ never took bowl of blood literally but His sacrifice covers all the foreshadowed events ( where they were many sacrifices he did it once and for all)

for day of atonement events we have to look elsewhere  where to find that prophecy ..not in revelation no dates are given but the metaphor for judgment events standout loud in revelation 11:1 when saints pass under  the rod..which is a hebrew metaphor for judgment or as "measuring the saints or counting the worshippers ".the announcement in revelation 14:6-7 is plain explanation for day of atonement events ..judgment !.Jews would naturally see that announcement  in revelation 14:6-7 as typical of feast of trumpet call announcing day of atonement (jUdgment ).still no date is given in revelation .no date is given in Daniel 7 either but if the symbols in Daniel 7 are identified as Babylon ,medo-persia.greece .Rome ,divided Rome then the court session ( day of atonement as metaphor) should occur  as last events .Christ s ministry at the cross and his ascension to heaven is called the DAILY service.His closing events are in the Most Holy place and thats the day of atonement ( a metaphor for judgment).Christs  blood remains active even during judgment when he is in the Most holy place